# Appending objects to list in a loop - not what I expected

Tags: python, iteration

I am appending a object to a list like this:

```
    json_object = []
    nodes = soup.findAll(params["node_name"])
    for node in nodes:
        obj = tags
        for element in node:
            if element.name != None:
              obj[element.name] = str(element.text)
        print obj
        json_object.append(obj)
        print json_object
```

Here is the output of the first two iterations:

```
{'sl_no': '1', 'sl_runs': '98', 'sl_name': 'Khumalo S', 'sl_wins': '12', 'sl_level': '-19.30', 'country': 'SA', 'date_from': '01 November 2013', 'sl_third': '12', 'sl_place': '8', 'sl_second': '16', 'stat_desc': u'Top Jockeys in South Africa ONLY 01 November 2013 to 20 November 2013', 'sl_wins_pc': '12.24', 'sl_winplace': '51.02', 'date_to': '20 November 2013', 'sl_fourth': '10', 'stat_type': u'Jockeys', 'region': 'South Africa ONLY', 'sl_stake_earned': 'R1 018 300'}
[{'sl_no': '1', 'sl_runs': '98', 'sl_name': 'Khumalo S', 'sl_wins': '12', 'sl_level': '-19.30', 'country': 'SA', 'date_from': '01 November 2013', 'sl_third': '12', 'sl_place': '8', 'sl_second': '16', 'stat_desc': u'Top Jockeys in South Africa ONLY 01 November 2013 to 20 November 2013', 'sl_wins_pc': '12.24', 'sl_winplace': '51.02', 'date_to': '20 November 2013', 'sl_fourth': '10', 'stat_type': u'Jockeys', 'region': 'South Africa ONLY', 'sl_stake_earned': 'R1 018 300'}]
{'sl_no': '2', 'sl_runs': '41', 'sl_name': 'Marcus A', 'sl_wins': '12', 'sl_level': '-8.70', 'country': 'SA', 'date_from': '01 November 2013', 'sl_third': '3', 'sl_place': '2', 'sl_second': '3', 'stat_desc': u'Top Jockeys in South Africa ONLY 01 November 2013 to 20 November 2013', 'sl_wins_pc': '29.27', 'sl_winplace': '48.78', 'date_to': '20 November 2013', 'sl_fourth': '2', 'stat_type': u'Jockeys', 'region': 'South Africa ONLY', 'sl_stake_earned': 'R690 750'}
[{'sl_no': '2', 'sl_runs': '41', 'sl_name': 'Marcus A', 'sl_wins': '12', 'sl_level': '-8.70', 'country': 'SA', 'date_from': '01 November 2013', 'sl_third': '3', 'sl_place': '2', 'sl_second': '3', 'stat_desc': u'Top Jockeys in South Africa ONLY 01 November 2013 to 20 November 2013', 'sl_wins_pc': '29.27', 'sl_winplace': '48.78', 'date_to': '20 November 2013', 'sl_fourth': '2', 'stat_type': u'Jockeys', 'region': 'South Africa ONLY', 'sl_stake_earned': 'R690 750'}, {'sl_no': '2', 'sl_runs': '41', 'sl_name': 'Marcus A', 'sl_wins': '12', 'sl_level': '-8.70', 'country': 'SA', 'date_from': '01 November 2013', 'sl_third': '3', 'sl_place': '2', 'sl_second': '3', 'stat_desc': u'Top Jockeys in South Africa ONLY 01 November 2013 to 20 November 2013', 'sl_wins_pc': '29.27', 'sl_winplace': '48.78', 'date_to': '20 November 2013', 'sl_fourth': '2', 'stat_type': u'Jockeys', 'region': 'South Africa ONLY', 'sl_stake_earned': 'R690 750'}]
```

As you can see it prints the first object with sl_no 1, then it adds it to the list

Then it prints the object with sl_no 2 but then both objects in the list is 2, and not 1 and 2 a I would have expected it... So at the end of the iteration the whole list has only the last object in as many times as the iterations were happening??

Why is this happening?

Comment: No its not really, I updated my syntax in the question..

Comment: @Mzzl I was mentioning the same, I think it's actually in the loop but in this post it's pasted wrong.

Comment: Yes that is the case :-)

Comment: yes, json = [] Ill add it the the question

Comment: `obj` is the same dictionary object each time, and it gets appended to the list several times. I don't know what `tags` is, but probably `obj = tags.copy()` will fix it.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich you should post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `obj` is the same object each time. You append it to the list `json` several times, so then that is a list that contains a number of references to the same object. `obj` changes over time, and then if you print the list you see the same object printed out several times.

Using

```
obj = tags.copy()
```

instead makes obj a *new* object each time (not a mere reference to the same object as tags, but a reference to a new dictionary with the same contents). So changes to this obj only affect this obj.

Comment: Thanks very much. It looks like the copy() function changes the order of the dict?

Comment: Dictionaries have no order.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior happens because of

```
    obj = tags
```

Actually, you are editing the content of `tags` on every iteration, resulting on an array with duplicated rows.

To solve your problem, just create a new instance of `tags` on each iteration.

For example:

```
    obj = []
```